# Jquery Accordion alternate colors

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui-accordion

Hi i have jquery accordion,
iam trying to give alternate colors upto 9th position its wokring fine but from 10th postion color is not getting effected,

```
     .ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header:first-of-type {
         background-color : #CACACA;
    }
   .ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header:nth-of-type(2) {
         background-color :  #B1DFE5
    } 
    .
    .
    .
   .ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header:nth-of-type(10) {
         background-color :  #B1DFE5
    }

     // This color is not getting applied
```

I have tried with other CSS code like

```
      .ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header:last-of-type{
         background-color :  #CACACA;
    }
    // This is also not working
```

Could any one please help me how to fill color from 10th postion to 15th position with alternate colors.

Here is my code in asp

```
         <div id="accordion">
           <h3>Project 1</h3>
              <div>
              <p><strong>TEAM:</strong>A, B , C </p> 
              </div>
              <h3>Project2 </h3>
              <div>
              <p><strong>TEAM:</strong>A, B , C </p> 
              </div>
              .
              .
              .

               <h3>Project 10 </h3>
              <div>
              <p><strong>TEAM:</strong>A, B , C </p> 
              </div>
              <h3>Project 11</h3>
              <div>
              <p><strong>TEAM:</strong>A, B , C </p> 
              </div>

        </div>
```

I want to show all these projects in accordion with alternate colors

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Add jsfiddle or add other required code

Comment: Can u please check my edited question

Comment: Can you update your html to add class? Then I can provide a simple way

Comment: It's working fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/raunakkathuria/sc7uL/2/

Comment: It is much easier to use nth-of-type(odd)  and (even) than to set all the posible numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its working fine for me [jsfiddle.net/raunakkathuria/sc7uL/2](http://jsfiddle.net/raunakkathuria/sc7uL/2)

But if you are facing problem with this approach, you can add class to your html then in simple way like this

```
<h3 class="class1">Project 1</h3> // add different class to every header
```

Then in css do this

```
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header.class1 { 
  background-color : #CACACA;
}
```

Check http://jsfiddle.net/raunakkathuria/sc7uL/3/